# update_post_meta() is not working for downloadable file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to run query for update woocommerce downloadable products. following code which i am using:

```
if($_FILES){
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'abe_update_epub', $post_id );
        if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
            $errors = $attachment_id->get_error_messages();
            foreach( $errors as $error ){
                echo $error;
            }
            echo 'There was an error uploading the image';
        } else {
            $file_name = 'Epub Files';
            $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
            $files[md5( $file_url )] = array(
                'name' => $file_name,
                'file' => $file_url
            );      
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable_files', $files );
            echo 'The image was uploaded successfully!';
     }
}
```

My file is successfully upload in media but it is not update my downloadable files in product. it is showing blank in downloadable files.

so please help me and tell me where i am doing wrong in code or some other code would be work?

Comment: Have you checked in database on `wp_postmeta` table, that **`'_downloadable_files'`** for a given `product_id` is empty after updating this product? … It could be also related to a data formatting problem…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i have checked wp_postmeta and found it is not empty.. it is showing like meta id - 5996, post_id - 2311, meta_key - downloads_files, meta_value - a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:14:"_wc_file_names";s:8:"PDF File";s:13:"_wc_file_urls";s:80:"http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/Cover-proof-for-Rosy-Book-One-3.pdf";}}

my file is successfully updated in database but not showing in my admin products and even i thought may be it will not show in admin so i purchased that product and check in email that i did not find download link in email also.

Comment: So your problem, is certainly in the kind formatted data that can't not be read once updated (Bad formatting). I can't help on this as I don't know how the data has to be formatted, but your problem is certainly there…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for help me.. i will try to take another solution.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, i found the error, actually i am giving space after '_downloadable_files ' so the meta field store _downloadable_files with space, so i remove and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Is better to delete this question Now… Good to know tha you solved the issue.